# Phonegap "hello world" app won't launch in android emulator?

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

I'd been using this tutorial: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.edu.html

To try to make the "hello world" program with PhoneGap but couldn't get it to launch on the emulator.  I gave up and used the example project that came with the PhoneGap download, and I can't get it to load on the emulator either.  I've messed around with the emulator for like an hour and nothing seems to work.

I used this to install the SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Also I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: If no errors, what's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: It won't appear on the emulator.  Or if it is I can't find it

Comment: Check your manifest. Do you have a launcher activity defined there?

Comment: solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display

Answer (score 0):

Check your preferences. Goto window->preferences and check whether you have given your android sdk path correct or not..

try [this you tube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfSL4KK4nzk&feature=youtu.be&t=13m28s) video for setting your android.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why my answer got deleted, but this is exactly the same problem I runned into (newbie trying to follow phonegap android tutorial, and it does not run in emulator). If I did

phonegap run android

it complained that it can't run it the emulator. I had to create "android virtual device" first:

android create avd -n blah -t 1

Then the above phonegap command does launch emulator and loads my app.

Perhaps the moderator that deleted my answer thinks that configuring emulator is obvious step not related to phonegap. He might be right, except for phonegap newbie like me (and maybe topic starter too) who only just installed android sdk this is not obvious at all, and we are left wondering why hello world does not pop up in the emulator.