# Cordova "hello world" app won't display

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Apache Cordova and **I can't get the Cordova "hello world" application to display on Android**. I'm talking about the default application obtained from the "cordova create" command from the CLI.

I read the documentation and installed everything as required (Node.js, npm, Cordova 5.0.0, I already had an Android SDK so i just needed to update the PATH).

Cordova tells me the build is a success.

It then says the application is launched, but the only thing that changes on device/emulator screen is that **a menu is opened** (like on the following picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7bI2.jpg

I tried on an emulator and on a real device, results are the same.

I checked the API version and it seems to be high enough (4.0.3).
I'm under Windows 7, with an Oracle JDK. I thought maybe a plugin was missing and installed cordova-plugin-device, but it did change nothing.

Is this a bug or do I miss something?
Is there some mean to get an error report (nothing unusual appears with the "cordova run android" command)?

Comment: Have you enabled debug mode in your phone? You can also try manually installing the APK.

Comment: I've got that problem too. Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956031/cordova-run-android-executes-fine-but-android-4-1-2-doesnt-start-the-app

Comment: Debugging mode is enabled. I didn't try to manually install the apk. If it is the same problem as ManBearPig, I guess it should work... I'll try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally got it figured.

Problem seemed to be that the apk was not properly installed. The application was in fact able to run when i installed it with the following command (as recommanded by jojo in [cordova run android executes fine. But Android 4.1.2 doesn't start the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956031/cordova-run-android-executes-fine-but-android-4-1-2-doesnt-start-the-app)): `adb install <path_to_apk>`

So I checked Cordova code to see what happens when apk is installed, and manually launched the command Cordova is using:

`adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"`

It returns: "Error: unknown option -d"!

**If you simply delete the "-d" option, applications run normally with
`cordova run android`.** On Cordova 5.0.0 you will find this commande at line 101 of file platforms\android\cordova\lib\device.js (and at line 311 of platforms\android\cordova\lib\emulator.js for `cordova emulate android`).

I don't know what this "-d" option is meant too... Is this a Cordova bug?

## EDIT

As joris says in comment :

> The `-d` is supposed to come directly after `adb` (as in `--device`) instead of after install. So you can just move it there instead of removing it.

Plus, [here is the opened issue on apache cordova issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8912)

Comment: The `-d` is supposed to come directly after `adb` (as in --device) instead of after `install`. So you can just move it there instead of removing it.

Comment: some months later.. and I still have the same problem. does anyone knows if cordova was updated to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Goto Platforms > android > cordova > lib > `Here you will find device.js and emulator.js`

> emulator.js

In `emulator.js` you must change the following line (311) from ->

`return exec('adb -s -d' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"', os.tmpdir())`

To `return exec('adb -d -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r "' + apk_path + '"')`

> device.js

In `device.js` you must change the following line (101) from ->

```
var cmd = 'adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"';
```

To `var cmd = 'adb -d -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r "' + apk_path + '"';`

Once you have changed these rebuild the application and run it on your emulator!

Comment: Solved my problem. I am using cordova 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that don't know where to find those files and use ionic they are in:

cordova\lib\device.js and cordova\lib\emulator.js 
in platform/android

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code in device.js and emulator.js didn't work for me (and in fact introduced an error where `cordova build android` wouldn't work anymore). My problem was completely different: I had two `<application>`s in my AndroidManifest.xml which is apparently not allowed.

Somewhere along the line I had added `<application android:debuggable="true" />` to my AndroidManifest.xml. However, that file *already* had an "application" element that looked like this:

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">`

So I added the "debuggable" line to the existing `<application>` (and removed the second `<application>`) like so:

`<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">`

After that I rebuilt using `cordova build android`, ran it successfully on my device with `cordova run android`, and then clapped my hands because it finally worked (and scared my dog).

HOWEVER, even if this isn't your issue, here's how I discovered the problem: I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30175500/3614438) and ran `adb logcat` with my device connected. That terminal tab immediately filled up with interminable crap.

Then I opened a new terminal window that I could view at the same time, I took note of the latest timestamp in the logcat output, and I ran `cordova run android`. The screen filled up with more crap, and then I scrolled back up to my starting time and reviewed it line by line. Eventually I found my culprit:

`PackageParser: <manifest> has more than one <application>`

Hope this helps!