# Cordova/Phonegap not launches the application in the emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-14.04, phonegap-build

After running `cordova run android` and build the application, open the emulator but never load the application. In the terminal returns

> LAUNCH SUCCESS

but it's not true. What's the problem?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit 
Cordova 5.0.0 
Phonegap 5.0.0-0.27.1 
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3

Comment: Does the emulator load fully?

Comment: start the emulator first, load the emulator completely, then try cordova run android

Comment: Try  `$ cordova emulate android`

Comment: @Zerkz the emulator stops here http://oi58.tinypic.com/2d0036t.jpg

Comment: @AtanuCSE your suggestion doesn't worked. Thanks.

Comment: @NehilMistry I tried, but not worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova "hello world" app won't display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the same problem as me ([Cordova "hello world" app won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display)). I found a way to pass through it (but I don't really understand the underlying causes).

On Cordova 5.0.0, adb commands to install the apk can be found at line 101 of file platforms\android\cordova\lib\device.js (and at line 311 of platforms\android\cordova\lib\emulator.js for cordova emulate android):

`adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"`

Current command returns to me: "Error: unknown option -d"! If you simply delete the "-d" option, applications run normally with cordova run android.